# A href wider than image or image positioned to the left

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is also a link. However the clickable area is wider than the actual image. Display img as inline does work, however this solution moves the image to the left, and I need it to be centered.
I've tried to center the image using `margin: auto`, `text-align: center`, and `align:middle` in the actual `html` file, no luck.

I know several others have asked the same question, but their solutions does not help me.

```css
/*Section2*/
#section2 {
  line-height: 1.8em;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#section2 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2.5em 0;
}
#section2 p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#section2 img {
  padding: 0 0.2em 2em;
  display: inline;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: auto;
}
#section2 a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="section2">
    <a href="http://wordpress.bysuonpera.com/">
        <img src="/Users/jonashansen/Desktop/hjemmeside/img/wordpress.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with bootstrap then you can put the image inside a col and give it an offset and make it to the centre horizontally the href link will also be as wide as the column you enter. it won't take the entire space. Take a look at the code that I have written, try it once:

```
 <div  id="section2" class="row">
    <a class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center col" href="http://wordpress.bysuonpera.com/"><img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually thought of this, but I wasn't sure (as I'm not that experienced) that the offset is the best way to align elements..

Comment: Yes, it is the easiest way to align elements horizontally in the center. It is even responsive :)

Comment: Should the image and the a elements both be block or inline? Or should I just leave them as the default?

Comment: Leave them as default.

Comment: Okay. last thing, how do I make the image the same size as the col? Because now this whole area is a clickable link: col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 .. Not just the image

Comment: Give the image  width and height of 100% so that it will occupy the whole space of the col. If you want to decrease or increase the image's size, you can use smaller or larger col numbers  so that the image size also gets resized along with the col

Comment: Works perfectly.. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome @suonpera :)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove padding, margin from image make height auto and this will do for you

**Update**

if you want to center align img and have full width as clickable, make a tag as block and assign `text-align: center`

```
#section2 a {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#section2 {
 line-height: 1.8em;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#section2 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bolder;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 2.5em 0;
}

#section2 p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#section2 img {
 padding: 0;
 display: inline;
 width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

#section2 a {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div  id="section2">
  <a href="http://wordpress.bysuonpera.com/"><img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the clickable area the same area as the image, but now the image is aligned to the left?

Comment: check my updated answer if this is what you are looking for@suonpera

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are adding padding to the image:

```css
#section2 img {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 0;
}

#section2 a {
  /*display: inline;*/
}
```

```html
<div  id="section2">
   <a href="http://wordpress.bysuonpera.com/"><img src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/21348043/3/stock-illustration-21348043-star-burst-and-sunbeam-background.jpg"></a>
  </div>
```